# How to add an application to the launcher menu of unity in my Ubuntu phone

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch, launcher, phone

How to add an application launcher menu of unity in my Ubuntu phone. 
Exactly on this side:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I don't completely understand what you're asking. If you wish to *pin* (lock permanently) one app icon to the launcher, then follow these steps:

1. Run the desired app
2. App icon should appear in the launcher, long-press on the app icon
3. A pop-up menu should appear, select **Pin shortcut** option

From now on this app icon should be present in the launcher all the time (even when the app is not running).

Comment: I want the application icon appears though you are not using .

Comment: @RicardoFernandez well, then follow the steps I listed in my answer. It should work.

Comment: Sorry , it's true , it works. Thx!!!